# Cannot find where JVisualVM has placed performance data

Tags: java, jvisualvm

Yesterday I tried profiling a java app using JVisualVM.
After some minutes I got a warning from the OS that the disk was being filled, once I understood the problem was JVisualVM and stopped it I 'lost' about 12Gb of storage (out of 256).
I'm trying to free up that space but could not find where is this data lost.

I've already tried the most common options with no success:

- search for any file larger then 500Mb
- look into %TEMP% and %TMP%
- overview with Overdisk to look for folders larger then 7Gb

Environment is:

- Windows 10 x64 (inside parallels desktop)
- JVisualVM from JDK 1.7.0._75 x64

any hints on how to resolve this are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Open Visualvm, click `Help > About > Details` and it shows you the user directory and cache directory where profiling files are stored.

Comment: thanks @wero but this did not work: none of those folders is so big to account for the used space